# assigning one shared_ptr to another

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

Does assigning one shared pointer to another free the memory managed by the latter? Let

```
typedef shared_ptr<char> char_ptr_t;
char_ptr_t pA(new char('A'));
char_ptr_t pB(new char('B'));
```

Now, does the below statement free the memory of `'A'`?

```
/*1*/ pA = pB;
```

Or do I need to explicitly free it:

```
/*2*/ pA.reset();
/*3*/ pA = pB;
```

And, is the following code valid for achieving the same?

```
/*4*/ pA.reset(pB); //<-- is this valid? Not compiling in MSVC++ 2010, though the standard seems to allow it.
```

Comment: The pointer wouldn't be very smart if the second example were correct

Comment: @aaronman, Incredulous me. My mental model about smart pointers is that they can be viewed/passed around as pointers that do not require freeing up. Probably, that's why I felt code line /*4*/ would compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `pA` does not point to the char `'A'` anymore, so the reference count is decremented. As it was the only reference to `'A'`, the reference count reaches zero and the char is deleted. It would be highly surprising and error-prone if you'd have to explicitly release the reference before reassignment.

`pA.reset(pB)` should not compile, as `reset` can only take a raw pointer, not another `shared_ptr`.

Comment: why is it error-prone to explicitly release the reference before reassignment?

Comment: @winterlight: Because you might forget to reset it, just like you might forget to `delete` a raw pointer. The point of `shared_ptr` (and `unique_ptr`) is to relieve the coder from having to remember to manually do things that can be done automatically.